# I am using loopback 3 and idInjection false is not working

Tags: loopbackjs

My database is in PostgreSQL.My model defination is as below -

```
{
  "name": "City",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I am using code below to auto update the tables but when I go to database after running the code below and I check fields, I see id field created with an auto increment. How can I prevent creation of "id" field ?

```
ds.autoupdate("City", function (er) {
  if (er) throw err
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent creation of "id" field?

If you're using a database, you can't.  See [this](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mssql/issues/1#issuecomment-42097140) issue.

> A model without any id properties can only be used without attaching to a database.

Making the `name` property an `Id` looks like the only way to use it with a relational database.

```
"name": {
  "type": "string",
  "id": 1
}
```